# $ is not defined (SharePoint + JS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint

This error keep showing up, so hopefully you throw some light here, my code is the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.2.min.js/"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/4.0/1/MicrosoftAjax.js/"></script>
<script type="text/ecmascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.runtime.js"></script>
<script type="text/ecmascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.js"></script>

<script>    
    function funcionX() {
        //$("#submit-button").click(function () {
            var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();

            alert('Entro');

            var movies = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("Movies");
            var movieCreationInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
            var movie = movies.addItem(movieCreationInfo);
            movie.set_item("Title", $("#movie-title").val());
            movie.set_item("MovieDescription", $("#movie-description").val());
            movie.update();
            context.load(movie);

            context.executeQueryAsync(success, failure);


        function success() {
            $("#movies-output").text("Created movie!");
        };
        function failure() {
            $("#movies-output").text("Something failded");
        };
    };
</script>

Title: <input type="text" id="movie-title" /> <br />
Description: <input type="text" id="movie-description" /> <br />
<button type="button" id="submit-button" onclick="funcionX()">Add Movie</button>

<div id="movies-output"></div>
```

I understand the error is because my browser is not recognizing jquery, right?

Thank you for your help and sorry for the bad english!

Comment: That error would certainly appear to show jQuery is not being included in the page. I'd start by using the F12 developer tools, network tab, and make sure that this script is being loaded correctly - `//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.2.min.js/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try JQuery noConflict and should solve the issue.

```
<script> 
$.noConflict(); 
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) { 
// Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here. }); 
// Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
</script>
```

Comment: Provide an example so he can understand your answer, this is the right one.

Comment: You can update your answer so your explanation is contained within, instead of leaving it on the Comments section where is less likely to be read.

Comment: VM15073:1 Uncaught TypeError: $.noConflict is not a function
    at <anonymous>:1:3

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the trailing slashs in your js libraries URLs:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.2.min.js/"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/4.0/1/MicrosoftAjax.js/"></script>
```

to:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/4.0/1/MicrosoftAjax.js"></script>
```